# SQL - Select everything that does not follow proper format

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to select  every row from a table which includes a faulty social security number. In this simple example the social security number has to be exactly 4 numbers long, using the numbers 0-9. The table looks something like this:

```
|SSN |Name  |Favorite Food|
|1345|Mark  |Meatballs    |
|1458|Connor|Tacos        |
|12  |Lisa  |Pizza        |
|1487|Clark |Tomato Soup  |
|XQXQ|Hans  |Sallad       |
```

I would like to select the name/names of the person(s) which do not have a correct SSN. The query should result in **Lisa** since she only has **2** numbers in her SSN and **Hans** which has written invalid characters. Thank you for reading this, have a nice one.

I don't know how important this is but just so I supply correct information, I use MySQL and the SSN is of the type "char".

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? And what is the data type of the SSN column?

Comment: Or, if the column is numeric, KISS: `where SSN >999 and SSN <10000` :-)

Comment: The datatype is a "char". I use innodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which database you are using but using the LIKE statement ...

```
select *
from Table
Where SSN not Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Check you database help for exact syntax

Comment: I got this to work with RLIKE instead of LIKE. Thank you, and have a nice one.

Comment: Using `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` it's possible to write pattern like '[0-9]{4}' for the example

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Length` function to get char. count..

```
select *
from Table
Where LENGTH(SSN)<>4
```

for ms-sql use `LEN`

Comment: This does seem logical but lists all the people from my table which do have the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE SSN < 1000
OR SSN < 9999
OR UPPER(SSN) <> LOWER(SSN);
```

Comment: Sure I could use the SSN < 5 but then I also need to know if the person typed in another sign than 0-9.

Comment: I have added more conditions for validation. Please see above. The `UPPER(SSN) <> LOWER(SSN)` condition would check for alphanumeric characters and special characters.